# Can't copy file with ansible 2.2 module

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

i am trying to perform a simple copy task between two servers using ansible, my playbook script is:

```
- hosts: 10.100.12.26
  remote_user: myUser
  vars:
    MERCHANT_API_DEST_DIR: "/tmp/"
    MERCHANT_API_SRC_DIR: "/source/folder/"
  tasks:
    - name: Copy the spring boot jar to the host destiny
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      copy:
        src: "{{item}}"
        dest: "{{MERCHANT_API_DEST_DIR}}"
      with_fileglob: "{{MERCHANT_API_SRC_DIR}}/file-name-*.jar"
```

When i execute the playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --ask-pass
```

I get the message:

```
fatal: [10.100.12.26]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/tmp/file-name-1.13.jar): MODULE FAILURE"}
```

I can't figure it out what the problem is, can someone help me?

Comment: It is a known bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found how to make it work, i add a command to the execution line:

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
```

Comment: Adding `--ask-become-pass` was sufficient in my case.

Comment: Correction: Adding `--ask-become-pass` is technically sufficient but you'll get prompted for passphrase for each connection. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue might result from having the [become] boolean wrongly indented